# Inverse of complex matrix using Gauss-Jordan method

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know how to find the inverse of
The following $2\times 2$ matrix using Gauss-Jordan method:
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
i & 1 \\
1 & i \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Multiply row one by $-i$...

Answer (score 1):

You want to write the matrix in augmented form as $[A | I]$, perform Gauss-Jordan elimination, and arrive at $[I | A^{-1}]$, so we have:

$$[A | I] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
    i & 1 & 1  & 0  \\
    1 & i & 0 & 1  \end{array}\right]$$

Perform the following row operations:

- $R_1: R_1 \times -i$
- $R_1: R_2 + R_1$
- $R_1: R_1/2$
- $R_2: -R_1 + R_2$
- $R_2: R_2/i$

We end up with $[I | A^{-1}]$ as:

$$[I | A^{-1}] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
    1 & 0 & -\dfrac{i}{2}  & ~~~~\dfrac{1}{2}  \\
    0 & 1 & ~~~\dfrac{1}{2} & -\dfrac{i}{2}  \end{array}\right]$$